# avoid hung sessions in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a procedure in pl/sql which works fine with small amount of data. The issue is, when is a large amount of data, cursor6 sometimes hangs session and other users can't access table5.
table5 has a primary key column "ocf" which is the user id, so each user access only rows coresponding his user id. Even under these conditions, the cursor6 locks the table5 and create a dead session and, I don't understand how, but it doesn't allow other users to access it
even if they use other rows in table5. Is there a solution to recreate that cursor for update or use something that may do the same thing, avoiding in this way that hanging session?

```
cursor cursor6(pf varchar2,PO number, psu varchar2) is select * from table5 where ocf=PO and .. for update;
row1 cursor6%rowtype;
BEGIN
   delete table5 where ocf=PO;
    commit;
    open cursor1;
    fetch cursor1 into wv,wd;
    if cursor1%found then
    open cursor2;
      fetch cursor2 into wf;
      if cursor2%found then
      while cursor2%found loop
          open cursor3;
          fetch cursor3 into wco;
          if cursor3%found then
            while cursor3%found loop
                open cursor5;
                  fetch cursor5 into ws;
                  while cursor5%found loop
                       open cursor4;
                       fetch cursor4 into ..;
                       if cursor4%found then
                            open cursor6(..);
                            fetch cursor6 into row1;
                            if cursor6%notfound then insert into table5 values (..);
                            else update table5 set ... where current of cursor6;    
                            end if;
                            close cursor6;
                       end if;
                       close cursor4;
                   end loop;
                close cursor5;
            end loop;
          end if;
          close cursor3;
        end loop;
       end if;
     close cursor2;
    end if;
    close cursor1;
    commit;
    delete table5 where ocf=PO;
    commit;
```

Comment: It absolutely looks like the majority of your query could be written as a single MERGE statement, that takes care of inserting or updating as appropriate. If you can encapsulate the logic in your count_first/second_part procedures into the MERGE statement, you might be able to do the delete in the same statement. Nested loops are, in general, a bad design decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gosh, good luck with 6 nested loops.

---

> cursor6 locks the table5 and create a dead session and, I don't understand how, but it doesn't allow other users to acces

That happens when foreign key columns aren't indexed. I suggest you check whether that's the case and - if so - create indexes.

---

Here's a query (author is **Tom Kyte**) (I don't have a link to the original, sorry; Google for it if you want) which displays unindexed foreign key constraints. I modified it a little bit by adding *what* to display:

- `PAR_WHAT`:

  - `0` - show only missing ones
  - `1` - show valid ones
  - `NULL` - show all

I suggest you first run it with `PAR_WHAT = 0`.

```
WITH forkey
     AS (SELECT DECODE (b.table_name, NULL, '****', 'ok') Status,
                a.table_name,
                a.columns column_1,
                b.columns column_2
           FROM (  SELECT SUBSTR (a.table_name, 1, 30) table_name,
                          SUBSTR (a.constraint_name, 1, 30) constraint_name,
                             MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        1, SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        2, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        3, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        4, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        5, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        6, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        7, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        8, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        9, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   10, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   11, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   12, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   13, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   14, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   15, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   16, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                             columns
                     FROM user_cons_columns a, user_constraints b
                    WHERE     a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                          AND b.constraint_type = 'R'
                 GROUP BY SUBSTR (a.table_name, 1, 30),
                          SUBSTR (a.constraint_name, 1, 30)) a,
                (  SELECT SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 30) table_name,
                          SUBSTR (index_name, 1, 30) index_name,
                             MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        1, SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        2, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        3, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        4, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        5, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        6, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        7, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        8, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        9, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   10, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   11, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   12, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   13, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   14, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   15, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   16, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                             columns
                     FROM user_ind_columns
                 GROUP BY SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 30),
                          SUBSTR (index_name, 1, 30)) b
          WHERE     a.table_name = b.table_name(+)
                AND b.columns(+) LIKE a.columns || '%'
                AND a.table_name NOT LIKE 'HEP_DP%')
  SELECT f.status,
         f.table_name,
         f.column_1,
         f.column_2
    FROM forkey f
   WHERE f.status =
            CASE
               WHEN :par_what = 1 THEN 'ok'
               WHEN :par_what = 0 THEN '****'
               ELSE f.status
            END
ORDER BY f.table_name, f.column_1, f.column_2;
```

Comment: A handy dandy script for a problem that doesn't get much attention. Unindexed foreign key columns have a characteristic symptom: if you are trying to find the source of a hang and are looking in `v$session` or `v$lock` and see `enq: TM – contention` then you probably have unindexed foreign keys. Run the script, find the columns, and index them.